# Problem with configuring WolframLanguageForJupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I'm trying to configure WolframLanguageForJupyter. This project can be found at: https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

I tried both the methods mentioned in that page, i.e., using a paclet and using the wls file in the git repository. I get the following error,

```
In[5]:= ConfigureJupyter["Add"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-kernelspec-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.kernelspecapp import KernelSpecApp
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.


ConfigureJupyter::notadded: 
   An error has occurred. The desired Wolfram Engine is not in "jupyter kernelspec list." See
    WolframLanguageForJupyter`Errors`$ConfigureError for the message that Jupyter returned when
    attempting to add the Wolfram Engine.
```

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what the output of this:
jupyter kernelspec list

Comment: @RajVerma It's just python3. Interestingly, when using CMD, jupyter kernelspec list gives me the same error that I mentioned in my question. It works fine with Anaconda prompt though. Could this be a problem with the environment variable?

Comment: yes as its supposed have libraries that won't be there when you use it with bare python.

Comment: Is there a fix to this problem?

Comment: use the virtualenv thats there with all the libs created from conda, activate that and give it a shot. Although I have never tried using a conda env with python env. (Souldn't be any different). But a simpler way is use conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to configure WolframLanguageForJupyter for an Anaconda installation (Windows).

[Git repo of WolframLanguageForJupyter.](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter)

The paclet that automatically configures Wolfram Engine for Jupyter notebook is simply incompatible with Anaconda installations. One fix to this problem is to not use Anaconda and use pip instead. But if you would like to keep your Anaconda installation, then try the following steps.

1. Make sure that your Anaconda installation path is added to the environment variables. You should basically have "$anaconda-installation$" and "$anaconda-installation$\Scripts" in your PATH environment variable.
2. Now create a virtual environment. To do this, run `conda create -n environment-name python=x.x anaconda` in cmd/powershell/anaconda prompt. This should create a virtual environment called *environment-name*. To switch into the virtual environment, run `conda activate environment-name` and to deactivate the virtual environment, run `conda deactivate`. To list all the environments, run `conda info -e`.

*Note: You might have to initialise the shell before switching to an environment if you are using cmd/powershell. To do this, simply run `conda init cmd.exe` or `conda init powershell`. Also, to delete your virtual environment, run `conda remove -n environment-name -all`.*

3. Now download the zip of the repo and extract it. Run a powershell window from the root of the folder. Now activate your virtual environment and run `.\configure-jupyter.wls add`. This should configure WolframLanguageForJupyter. To check if everything has been configured correctly, run `jupyter kernelspec list`. This should list Wolfram Engine, if successfully configured.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I tried many options and there was only your option that worked for me !